# For-loop not looping multiple times in range of a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

expected boolean to return true but received false

```
def thing(a):
  b = 1
  c = 2
  for x in range(len(a)):
    if b == a[x:x+1] and c == a[x+1:x+2]:
      return True
    else:
      return False
print(thing([1,3,4,1,2]))
```

Comment: You always return on your first iteration, is that really what you want?

Comment: Additionally, an integer can never be equivalent to a list, which is what the list-slicing syntax produces.

Comment: The `if` condition will never be true. `b` and `c` are numbers, list slices are lists. They can't be equal.

Comment: `return false` should not be inside the loop. It should be at the end so you return `false` if the loop doesn't find a match.

Comment: You appear to think that `a[x:x+1]`  is an integer, because you are testing it for equality with an integer. But it isn't an integer, it is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iteration isn't comparing the actual contents of the list to `b` and/or `c`.  A simpler way of doing what you're trying to do is to iterate over a `zip` of the list with a slice of itself:

```
>>> def thing(a):
...     b = 1
...     c = 2
...     for x, y in zip(a, a[1:]):
...         if (x, y) == (b, c):
...             return True
...     return False
...
>>> thing([1,3,4,1,2])
True
>>> thing([1,3,4,1,3])
False
```

Comment: If you really want simple, do `return (b, c) in zip(a, a[1:])` or `return (b, c) in pairwise(a)` (the latter with Python 3.10's itertools).

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing numbers to list slices, they can never be equal, even if you're just slicing a single element. You need to compare with specific list indexes, not slices.

Subtract 1 from the list length so you don't get an invalid index when you access `a[x+1]` at the end.

```
def thing(a):
    b = 1
    c = 2
    for x in range(len(a)-1):
        if b == a[x] and c == a[x+1]:
            return True
    return False

print(thing([1,3,4,1,2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, looks like you want to check if two consecutive numbers are found in the list. Here is a fix of your code:

```
def thing(a):
  b = 1
  c = 2
  for x in range(len(a)-1):
    if b == a[x] and c == a[x+1]:
      return True
  return False
print(thing([1,3,4,1,2]))
```

Errors:

1- you should only return False after the loop

2- you need to loop until length - 1 as you take x+1, else you would hat an IndexError

3- you should only slice the element you want, not a range, if you're comparing to an element

###### alternating with slicing as list:

```
def thing(a):
  b = 1
  c = 2
  for x in range(len(a)-1):
    if a[x:x+2] == [b, c]:
      return True
  return False
```